# failed to install imagine class with require(vendor/autoload.php error on centos6.5/php5.4

Tags: php, centos, composer-php, php-imagine

I know many users have asked same question before but it wasn't helpful for me... 
I have a VPS (centOS6.5/directadmin/php5.4/SSH terminal)

I try install imagine (https://imagine.readthedocs.org) class  in my server via getcomposer.org

These are my all steps:

First I install getcomposer:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

then:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
```

And

```
   echo '{"require": {"imagine/imagine": "~0.6.2"}}'->composer.json
```

After That I run it:

```
composer update
```

OK! everything seems installed!

Now in my website root, I want to test it:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // line 2
$imagine = new Imagine\Gd\Imagine();   // line 3



?>
```

But I get this error:

> Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   /home/admin/domains/example.com/public_html/info.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php54/lib/php') in
>   /home/admin/domains/example.com/public_html/info.php on line 2

**//EDIT**

The real locate of autoload.php in my server:

```
/usr/local/bin/vendor/autoload.php
```

Also There "imagine" directory in vendor directory!

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/local/bin` is where your binary files live. You should move `composer.phar` to this location (and rename it to `composer`) and then use `composer` in your command line.

The `composer.json` file is part of your package, it specifies the packages it depends on in this file. You then can install all required packages for the current package by using `composer install`/`composer update`. This will make a `vendor` directory with all third party code and a preconfigured autoloader in `vendor/autoload.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly after install imagine class, I moved the composer to root of my website and  now it works normally